# Get the difference in % of the last records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next table:

```
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
| ID | market_id | last_value | timestamp |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 1  |    1      |     10     |   1001    |
| 2  |    1      |     15     |   1002    |
| 3  |    1      |     25     |   1003    |
| 4  |    1      |     30     |   1004    |
| 5  |    1      |     05     |   1005    |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

And my idea is something similar this:

```
SELECT id, market_id, last_value, timestamp from data_markets
where from_unixtime(timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%m:%s') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%m-%Y 00:00:00') and market_id = 1
```

With this, I get the all rows of today but i know as use join for get this:

```
+---+----------------------+--------------------+----------+
| market_id |    change    |    total_change    |  is_down |
+-----------+--------------+--------------------+----------+
|     1     |     83.3%    |      -50.00%       |   true   |
+-----------+--------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Explanation:

- Change: this value is the difference with the last row
- Total_change: this value is the difference of all rows in "24 hours"
- is down: it's possibly know if the value is increasing or decreasing respect the total change?

Edit:

I edit the example, in total_change I like the difference with all rows, but this is not possible can be the difference with the first row.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by total change in last 24 hours? What if there is simultaneously a much larger and much smaller value in the last 24 hours? That would create two very different total change values. Or did you mean the 24-hour average?

Comment: @Jay: I think he wants to compare one row with the others, and print the changes in percentages (%) of the changes. If last value is 10 and second-to-last value is 20, the change is 100% (I think).The total_change is this percentage for 1 whole day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that I think gives you most of what you want.

```
SELECT
    dm.id,
    dm.market_id,
    dm.last_value,
    (@prev_value := (SELECT last_value FROM data_markets WHERE (id < dm.id AND market_id = dm.market_id) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)) AS prev_value,
    ROUND((@24hr_value := (SELECT AVG(last_value) FROM data_markets WHERE (timestamp >= (dm.timestamp - 86400) AND timestamp < dm.timestamp AND market_id = dm.market_id))),1) AS 24hr_value,
    ROUND(IF(@prev_value,(((dm.last_value - @prev_value) / @prev_value) * 100),0),1) AS percent_change,
    ROUND((@24hr_change := IF(@24hr_value,(((dm.last_value - @24hr_value) / @24hr_value) * 100),0)),1) AS 24hr_change,
    IF(@24hr_change < 0, 'down', IF(@24hr_change > 0, 'up', '-')) AS direction
FROM
    data_markets dm,
    (SELECT
        @prev_value:=0,
        @24hr_value:=0,
        @24hr_change:=0
    ) r
WHERE
    dm.market_id = 1
ORDER BY
    dm.id ASC
```

You didn't explain how orders should determine the row's "previous" value. I assumed you wanted to determine this by a mix of the previous numerical `id` value, along with assuring the market_id was the same. Let me know if I misunderstood and it was something else. I then calculate the percent change for the last value, and the percent change from the AVERAGE last value for the last 24 hours. Finally, the 24 hour percentage determines the "direction" column. Here's the input data, slightly tweaked from what you provided:

```
===========================================
|id | market_id | last_value | timestamp  |
===========================================
|1  | 1         | 10         | 1290347095 |
|2  | 1         | 15         | 1370347095 |
|3  | 1         | 25         | 1390345341 |
|4  | 1         | 30         | 1390346043 |
|5  | 1         | 5          | 1390347095 |
===========================================
```

And the final result set:

```
===============================================================================
|id | market_id | last_value | prev | 24hr | change | 24hr_change | direction |
===============================================================================
| 1 | 1         | 10         | NULL | NULL | 0.0    | 0.0         | -         |
| 2 | 1         | 15         | 10   | NULL | 50.0   | 0.0         | -         |
| 3 | 1         | 25         | 15   | NULL | 66.7   |  0.0        | -         |
| 4 | 1         | 30         | 25   | 25.0 | 20.0   | 20.0        | up        |
| 5 | 1         | 5          | 30   | 27.5 | -83.3  | -83.6       | down      |
===============================================================================
```